# How to apply chmod recursively within a smbclient prompt?

Tags: permissions, samba, chmod, smb

I am logged in to some server with smbclient and I am sharing a LaTeX project (contained in `directory`) with other people. Currently, all files seem to have permissions 600. For other people to be able to collaborate, they (i.e. anyone) must be able to modify all files within that directory. However,

`chmod -R 777 directory`

returns 
`NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`
How do I apply `chmod` recursively within a smbclient prompt?

Comment: is `directory` on an NTFS filesystem? Also note that setting `666` on a directory will make it completely inaccessible to everyone (please see the permissions tag wiki)

Comment: You should use `chmod -R 777 directory` which will give permissions to all files currently in the folder and files added in the future without giving permissions to the directory itself.

Comment: @Arduino_Sentinel that does change the permissions of the directory itself

Comment: @Arduino_Sentinel this returns "NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER".

Comment: @Zanna I have no idea. I am not the admin.

Comment: @Arduino_Sentinel , the syntax is also ```chmod 777 -R directory``` but that returns the same error.

Comment: Yeah it seems the filesystem does not support Linux file permissions. I don't know about samba but afaik you will need to adjust the mount options to fix permissions. If you are not the admin, I would suggest asking them!

Comment: @Zanna there's no way that it could depend on how *I* mounted the share? At the moment I used ```smbclient "server adress" -U username```. I also seem to be able to change the mode for individual files. Are there smbclient alternatives?

Comment: @Zanna ,sure!i forgot  that i used  the `directory` it self

Comment: By the way,as @Zanna said,it might be hard in your condition to fix the problem as you are not the admin

Comment: Possibly you should use `smb.conf`, if the mount options allow read/write? I  don't have experience with smb, I just commented originally because I saw an ill-advised `chmod` :/ I hope someone with the right expertise finds your question. I will upvote it now...

Comment: Remember when accessing file server via Samba that you are accessing files in the windows world and the access rights are not managed the same way.  So, it does not surprise me too much that you get such an error message. On what kind of server does `directory`reside?  Do you have any control on it?

Comment: I have no control over it. Behaviour is also very erratic: 2 Windows users and 1 Ubuntu user were able to modify the files earlier. Using Nautilus to view the permissions shows "Unable to display permissions".  Maybe I should just recreate everything locally, change the permissions and then upload the files.

Comment: did you manage to fix it in the end?

Comment: No I gave up, SMB servers shouldn't be used for collaborative LaTeX projects anyway :P I think it's not supported due to the NTFS filesystem.. Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)